# Data Filter - View User Interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have an Asp.Net MVC web app that I need to provide a user interface in the view to apply data filters to display a subset of the data.

I like the design of what is used on fogbugz with a popup treeview that allows for the selection of data filters in a very concise manner: http://bugs.movabletype.org/help/topics/basics/Filters.html

My controller's action method has some nullable parameter's for all of the available filters:

```
public ActionResult EmployeeList(int? empId, int? month, int? year,
                                 string tag1, string tag2 //and others....)
{
   //...filter employee list on any existing parameters
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

My intention was whenever a filter was applied by clicking on a link, entering text...that filter would be added to the parameter list and reload the page with the correct data to display.

Looking for some guidance or examples on how to create a filter toolbar or best practices for this type of problem.  I haven't been able to find a jquery ui plugin or javascript library to do something similar to this so a little lost on where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this by having a main page containing a number of dropdowns containing the parameter options, then a div that had the resultant set ViewUserControl loaded into it on both page load and on dropdown selection change.  The controller for the data, in this case TaskList, just needs to return a normal ActionResult View(newTaskList(data)); Example below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataSet();
});

function loadDataSet(){
     var status = document.getElementById('ddlStatus');
     var selectedStatus = status.options[status.selectedIndex].value;
     if (status.selectedIndex == 0) selectedStatus = '';

     $.post('<%= Url.Action("TaskList") %>', { status: selectedStatus },
            function (data) {
                $('#divTaskList').html(data);
            });

     }
</script>

<%= Html.DropDownList("ddlStatus", Model.StatusOptions, null, new { onchange = "javascript:loadDataSet();" })%>

<div id='divTaskList' />
```